# Angular.js ng-repeat doesn't display content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load some content using ng-repeat with Angular.js. I set up a controller which will create an array, and corresponding HTML uses ng-repeat to display all elements in the array.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-group" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
<p class="list-group-item cat" ng-repeat="element in ctrl.current_articles">{{ element }}</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('newsclassifier', [])

.controller('MainController', ['$http', function($http){
  var self = this;
  self.current_articles = [1,2,3,4,5];

}]);
```

Now on running this code, I am able to see that rows for 5 elements are being created in the corresponding div. However, no content is displayed.
I tried using even the $scope syntax, but to no difference. I am running version 1.4.8 of Angular.js.
Is there something amiss here?

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your markup.

```
ng-controller="ctrl as MainController"
```

should be

```
ng-controller="MainController as ctrl"
```

Comment: oh that was a typo. Not the actual problem though. Updated the question with the changes. Something else might be the problem

Comment: @SaurabhSood Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @SaurabhSood yep, it works fine, here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdpi4YHdB4CT351DAfbd?p=preview)

Comment: Looks to be working in the Plunker. However when I put it in my code, it stops working

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any errors. In fact, I can see that 5 rows are being created. Just that there is no content. Even inspecting doesn't show any data.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to css. Anyhow, you'll have to upload a plunker.